# Не находится опубликованное приложение

Tags: android, google-play

Опубликовал приложение в маркете.Прошло 2 дня а по имени его не могу найти, только по имени пакета.Пробовал менять имя результат тот же.С таким именем находит подобные приложения,да и другие то же где в имени имеется имя + еще что.Было такое один раз так изменил имя и оно сразу стало находится.В чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?Может при поиске по имени коим образом учитывается и имя пакета.

Comment: Вы хоть ссылки приложите. И скрин консоли разработчика. Вы точно в прод залили, а не альфа/бета билд?

Comment: @Suvitruf да куда надо залил ведь не первый раз.Выяслил такую вещь.Если приложение назвать My App с пакетом com.myapps.ap.То при поиске My App не найдет, а myapps найдет.Если назвать My App с пакетом com.my.app то будет искать по имени My App.

Answer (score 3):

Алгоритм поиска неизвестен, предполагается, что используется некий алгоритм оптимизации/пессимизации поисковой строки с учетом имени приложения, имени пакета, названия тегов, описания, количества загрузок, общей оценки, отзывов и т.д. и т.п.

Так что - общего рецепта нет.

Есть некое ощущение, что все таки описание приложения и названия тегов - имеют несколько больший вес.